# Unable to GET data from ajax (get)

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem with my code ...

I have a page named "listeclients.php" which have several clients with id's etc.
I just made a little button in order to send some data to a page named "actionclient.php", which just has to display the parameters I send to it.
The actionclient.php consists in this :

```
<?php
echo "test = ";
echo $_GET['test'];
echo $_GET['test2'];
?>
```

(It's just a test page).

And here's my jQuery script :

```
$( "div.modif_dialog").click(function(e4) {
    $( "#editer" ).dialog("open");
    var monUrl4 = 'actionclient.php?action=modifier&id=';
    var url_final4 = monUrl4+pos4;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_final4,
        data: { test: "TEST", test2: pos4},
        success: function(){
           alert (pos4);
        }
    });
    $('#editer').load(monUrl4, function(response4, status4) {
        $('#test_dialog2').html(response4);
    });
    e4.preventDefault();
});
```

My alert with alert(pos4) works great, and the variables are all correct.

The actionclient.php (url_final4) is well loaded in my dialogbox, but it always just print :
    "test = "

Any clue ?
(I did exactly the same code with a POST method in an another page and it works great... I don't understand.)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

to see the sended vars you should do :

```
....
success: function(data){
   alert (data); //that will show (test= TEST pos4)
   }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The succes function should be like this :

```
success:function(html){ 
    alert("AJAX response :"+html);
}
```

actually you're just displaying same argument that you send before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your dialig box does not display the posted values, is that you are loading `actionclient.php` twice - once in your `$.ajax` call, and then again with `$('#editer').load`. There's nothing in `actionpclient.php` that saves anything on the server, thus the values do not show up when you request `actionclient.php` the second time.

What you seem to want, is to use the values returned by `actionclient.php` in your first request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_final4,
    data: { test: "TEST", test2: pos4},
    success: function(response){
        $('#test_dialog2').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It seems now logic...
But I have now an other problem...

The dialogbox just remains void... My page actionclient.php doesn't show up in the dialogbox with the code you gave.

In the page I made a :
    `<div id="test_dialog2">Test</div>`

But it won't display anything in my dialogbox...

Any clue ?

Thanks for your response !

Comment: Ah, I see now that `response.responseText` is wrong ... it should be just `response`. I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EhQtB/1/ - please note that you won't get a successful AJAX response when running the code at jsfiddle.net - you have to download it and run it on your own server.